# What is the meaning of the AllowInsecureAuthInProduction REST API metadata element?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

This element appears in the documentation of adding REST services to B2C, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw I am not clear what it means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that it isn't the best practice to allow anonymous authentication from Azure AD B2C to a REST API -- although anonymous authentication might be needed for a REST API that doesn't support secure authentication -- then the **AllowInsecureAuthInProduction** setting has to be added (as a "fail-closed" switch) to enable you to set the **AuthenticationType** setting to `None`.

Therefore, the following settings are valid:

```xml
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
  <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
</Metadata>
```

And, the following settings are invalid:

```xml
<Metadata>
  <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
  <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
</Metadata>
```